# AWS mobile hub sign in function issue

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub, amazon-mobile-hub

I am using the AWS mobile hub sign in function. My goal is to have user to sign in (no need for sign up), so I created the pool through the mobile hub. I have gone through the integration guide for setting up and calling the sign in UI. However , by running the app, I got below error , do I still miss something ? Is there a more specific tutorial which I can take a look ? User I created in the pool do work, I tried different password , it display password not matched, but sign in ui does not disappear with correct password.
Below is the error log.

Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7fb75c2277b0  (not loaded)
Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.service.cognitoidentity.AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper Code=0 "Obtaining an identity id in another thread failed or didn't complete within 5 seconds." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Obtaining an identity id in another thread failed or didn't complete within 5 seconds.}
Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Could not successfully update network info during initialization.

Thanks

Comment: Check your Federated Identities setup via AWS console. Also post your code for setting up your credential provider.

Comment: AWS guide does not mention it. I just want to use the user pool by AWS login UI , not the federated.Do I still need to set it up ?

Comment: Oh, I really hate the Amazon docs. It is mentioned, e.g. "When your mobile app is saved, Mobile Hub creates an Amazon Cognito identity pool".  Anyway, you need to have the temporary AWS credentials to access other AWS services (such as Dynamo DB mentioned in your error message). I suspect your user pool sign in is working (you get the web token) but something is misconfigured in your identity pool and/or credential provider.

Comment: I am using the mobile hub to create it automatically. I tried it on the real phone, "Could not successfully update network info during initialization." message disappear , however , the login page stays there forever. It can detect the wrong password I created in the pool, but do nothing with the correct user name and password , any ideal ?

Comment: @jing can you send tell us your mail id or open a customer support case with AWS? we will be able to get you unblocked from the issue.